# How to interact with foreground notification button in flutter

Tags: flutter, foreground-service

I want to change the text into notification button's id.

For example, when I press Send button, the Stop text will change into sendButton.

How can I do that?

[image: Foreground notification]

[image: App body]

This is my whole code:

```
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_foreground_task/flutter_foreground_task.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String text = "STOP";

  void _initForegroundTask() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.init(
      androidNotificationOptions: AndroidNotificationOptions(
        channelId: 'foreground_service',
        channelName: 'Foreground Service Notification',
        channelDescription:
            'This notification appears when the foreground service is running.',
        channelImportance: NotificationChannelImportance.LOW,
        priority: NotificationPriority.LOW,
        iconData: const NotificationIconData(
          resType: ResourceType.mipmap,
          resPrefix: ResourcePrefix.ic,
          name: 'launcher',
        ),
        buttons: [
          const NotificationButton(id: 'sendButton', text: 'Send'),
          const NotificationButton(id: 'testButton', text: 'Test'),
        ],
      ),
      iosNotificationOptions: const IOSNotificationOptions(
        showNotification: true,
        playSound: false,
      ),
      foregroundTaskOptions: const ForegroundTaskOptions(
        interval: 5000,
        isOnceEvent: false,
        autoRunOnBoot: true,
        allowWakeLock: true,
        allowWifiLock: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initForegroundTask();
    Future.microtask(() async {
      isRun = await FlutterForegroundTask.isRunningService;
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  bool isRun = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WithForegroundTask(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("foreground"),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton(
                child: isRun
                    ? const Icon(Icons.pause)
                    : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (await FlutterForegroundTask.isRunningService) {
                    await FlutterForegroundTask.clearAllData();
                    await FlutterForegroundTask.stopService();
                  } else {
                    await FlutterForegroundTask.startService(
                      notificationTitle: "notificationTitle",
                      notificationText: "notificationText",
                      callback: startCallback,
                    );
                  }
                  isRun = await FlutterForegroundTask.isRunningService;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
              Text(text),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void startCallback() {
  // The setTaskHandler function must be called to handle the task in the background.
  FlutterForegroundTask.setTaskHandler(FirstTaskHandler());
}

class FirstTaskHandler extends TaskHandler {
  SendPort? _sendPort;

  @override
  void onStart(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    _sendPort = sendPort;

    final customData =
        await FlutterForegroundTask.getData<String>(key: 'customData');
    print('customData: $customData');
  }

  @override
  void onRepeatEvent(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    // Send data to the main isolate.
    sendPort?.send(timestamp);
  }

  @override
  void onDestroy(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {}

  @override
  void onNotificationButtonPressed(String id) {
    print('onNotificationButtonPressed >> $id');

    // this part is what I did.
    // if (id == "sendButton") {
    //   text = "send";
    // }
    // if (id == "testButton") {
    //   text = "test";
    // }
  }

  @override
  void onNotificationPressed() {
    // FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp("/resume-route");
    _sendPort?.send('onNotificationPressed');
  }
}
```

And this part is what I did.

```
@override
  void onNotificationButtonPressed(String id) {
    print('onNotificationButtonPressed >> $id');

    // this part is what I did.
    // if (id == "sendButton") {
    //   text = "send";
    // }
    // if (id == "testButton") {
    //   text = "test";
    // }
  }
```